# Javascript Copy Text not working

Tags: javascript

I try to implement the following javascript example on my own:

https://jsfiddle.net/bt3v3rst/

I have created 2 files:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>hello</p>
        <button id="copy">Copy</button>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>    
    </body>
</html>
```

1.js

```
// Copies a string to the clipboard. Must be called from within an event handler such as click.
// May return false if it failed, but this is not always
// possible. Browser support for Chrome 43+, Firefox 42+, Edge and IE 10+.
// No Safari support, as of (Nov. 2015). Returns false.
// IE: The clipboard feature may be disabled by an adminstrator. By default a prompt is
// shown the first time the clipboard is used (per session).
function copyToClipboard(text) {
    if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.setData) {
        // IE specific code path to prevent textarea being shown while dialog is visible.
        return clipboardData.setData("Text", text); 

    } else if (document.queryCommandSupported && document.queryCommandSupported("copy")) {
        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.textContent = text;
        textarea.style.position = "fixed";  // Prevent scrolling to bottom of page in MS Edge.
        document.body.appendChild(textarea);
        textarea.select();
        try {
            return document.execCommand("copy");  // Security exception may be thrown by some browsers.
        } catch (ex) {
            console.warn("Copy to clipboard failed.", ex);
            return false;
        } finally {
            document.body.removeChild(textarea);
        }
    }
}

document.querySelector("#copy").onclick = function() {
    var result = copyToClipboard("longlonglongtext");
    console.log("copied?", result);
};

function myFunction() 
{
    alert("Hello");
}
```

The second button alert which displays "Hello" on the screen is working, the first one does not, which suppose to copy "longlonglongtext" to the keyboard.

This is not a browser issue since the example from jsfiddle works perfectly with my firefox 47.

What can be the problem?

Comment: You have made changes to the fiddle, it doesn't match the code above. It works as far as I can tell, "longlonglongtext" was copied to my clipboard

Comment: "This is not a browser issue since the example from jsfiddle works perfectly with my firefox 47."  This isn't sound reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** The way you are trying to define event handler for "copy" button  in javascript (1.js file) before element is rendered or available.

```
document.querySelector("#copy").onclick = function() {
    var result = copyToClipboard("longlonglongtext");
    console.log("copied?", result);
};
```

You can solve this problem different ways.

**Solution 1:** Move script tag which references 1.js file before the end of body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
```

e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>hello</p>
        <button id="copy">Copy</button>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Solution 2:** Make use of "DOMContentLoaded" event listner

e.g.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.querySelector("#copy").onclick = function() {
        var result = copyToClipboard("longlonglongtext");
        console.log("copied?", result);
    };
})
```